# $K$-topology of the real line and quotient topology.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, quotient-spaces

Let $K$ be the set $\{1,1/2,1/3,\cdots,1/n,\cdots\}$, which is the set of reciprocal of all positive integers. The $K$-topology on $\mathbb R$ is defined as generated by the usual open intervals $(a,b)$ and also $(a,b)-K$. For the text below allow me to write $\mathbb R_K$ for the $K$-topology.

The question is: Let $Y$ be the quotient space obtained from $\mathbb R_K$ by collapsing the set $K$ to a point; let $p:\mathbb R_K\to Y$ be the quotient map. Show that $Y$ satisfies the $T_1$ axiom, but is not Hausdorff.

I let $p(1/n)=b$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z_+$, it also map other real numbers into itself. From here I'm understanding that $Y=(\mathbb R\setminus K)\cup\{b\}$, where $b$ can be an element of $K$, or can not.

I can show that $Y$ satisfies $T_1$-axiom. Another problem want me to show that $Y$ is not a Hausdorff space, so I need to find two different point $x_1,x_2$ in $Y$ so that every pair of their respective neighborhood $U_1,U_2$ has nontrivial intersection, right?

My work is as follow: If $b\neq 0$, then we can consider the two points $b,0$ in $Y$. If $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$, then there is $r>0$ such that $(-r,r)\subset U$. If $V$ is a neighborhood of $b$, this means $p^{-1}(V)$ is open in $\mathbb R_K$. But this means $p^{-1}(V)$ contains $K$, so it contains every open set $(1/n-r_n,1/n+r_n)$ for some appropriate $r_n$. Maps this back to $Y$ we see $V$ contains these neighborhoods $(1/n-r_n,1/n+r_n)\setminus\{1/n\}$. Therefore, for $n$ large enough, $1/n$ would smaller than $r$, this makes $U$ and $V$ intersects, then we are done.

However, if $b=0$ then I've no idea how to choose the other point. I think I've messed up some concept about the quotient space.

From: Munkres General Topology, Chapter 22 Question 6(a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally the quotient space $Y$ is actually the set

$$\big\{\{x\}:x\in\Bbb R\setminus K\big\}\cup\{K\}\;;$$

its points are the sets $\{x\}$ for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus K$ and the set $K$. However, in this case there is no real harm in thinking of the quotient as $X=(\Bbb R\setminus K)\cup\{b\}$, where each $x\in\Bbb R\setminus K$ corresponds to the point $\{x\}$ in the quotient, and the point $b$ of $X$ corresponds to the point $K$ of the quotient; you just have to make sure that you get the topology right, which you did when you described a nbhd of $b$. And just as the point $K$ of the quotient is different from each of the points $\{x\}$ for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus K$ — in particular, $K\ne\{0\}$ — so your point $b$ is different from each of the other points of $X$, and in particular, it is not $0$: $b\ne 0$. And as you correctly showed, $0$ and $b$ do not have disjoint open nbhds in $X$, so $X$ is not Hausdorff, and neither is $Y$.

Comment: So what you mean is $b$ is a point generally different from the other point, so we don't need to consider when $b=0$? If that is the case, I understand. 
What if I define $p:\mathbb R_K\to \mathbb R\setminus K$ like this: $p(K)=\{0\}$ and $p(x)=x$ for $x\notin K$. Is $Y=\mathbb R\setminus K$ still not Hausdorff?

Comment: From the text I learnt, a quotient map $p$ is a surjective map, so it is still possible that I can define $p(0)=0$ and $p(1/n)=0$ for $n\in \mathbb Z_+$. If this is the case how should I interpret $K\neq \{0\}$?

Comment: @kelvinhong方: You’re confused about what the quotient space actually is, I think. You have a partition of $\Bbb R_K$ into parts; for each $x\in\Bbb R\setminus K$, the set $\{x\}$ is one of those parts, and $K$ is the remaining part. If $Y$ denotes the quotient space, $$Y=\big\{\{x\}:x\in\Bbb R_K\setminus K\big\}\cup\{K\}\;;$$ its **points** are the sets $\{x\}$ for $x\in\Bbb R_K\setminus K$ and the set $K$. And you don’t get to choose the quotient map $q:\Bbb R_K\to Y$: by definition, for each $x\in\Bbb R_K$, $q(x)$ is the unique member of the partition containing $x$. ...

Comment: Now I understand, Thanks for your help!

Comment: ... If $x\in\Bbb R_K\setminus K$, then $q(x)=\{x\}\in Y$. If $x\in K$, then $q(x)=K\in Y$. And a set $U\subseteq Y$ is open in $Y$ iff $q^{-1}[U]$ is open in $\Bbb R_K$.

Comment: @kelvinhong方: You’re welcome!